# Windows Service 'System.TypeInitializationException' ao iniciar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exceção

Olá,

Estou criando um serviço do windows para realizar uma tarefa de backup. Já criei outros serviços antes mas nunca tive um problema parecido.

Estava tudo correndo bem, durante o desenvolvimento eu instalei o serviço em um computador e estava executando-o normalmente para fazer os testes e ajustes, um pouco antes de finalizar o trabalho o serviço parou de rodar, sempre que inicializava ele mostrava a seguinte mensagem no eventvwr:

> Application: Backup67.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.TypeInitializationException Stack:    at
>   WinService.WinService.Main()

E logo em seguida este:

> Faulting application name: Backup67.exe, version: 0.0.0.0,
>
> time stamp: 0x552c2561
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229,
>
> time stamp: 0x51fb1116 Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
>
> Faulting process id: 0x2bec
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d07627884c559e
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Backup67.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: c5fb41de-e21a-11e4-a82f-001e67aaf90c

Achei estranho e tentei executar o processo na minha máquina pelo f5 do visual studio, o mesmo erro apareceu:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: O inicializador de tipo de
>   'WinService.WinService' acionou uma exceção.

Estive tentando debugar, mas não consigo, pois aparentemente o sistema não chega nem a executar o serviço, ele é parado antes que possa entrar em qualquer breakpoint ou Catch que eu possa colocar. Já tentei usar o AppDomain para as UnhandledExceptions mas sem sucesso também.

Estou procurando por uma solução desde então, tentei trocar o framework, trocar o tipo de CPU, mas nada disso funcionou. O que estou achando estranho é que o programa estava funcionando até pouco antes do erro, perfeitamente, não houve nenhuma alteração no sistema, apenas troquei o nome de uma variável e este erro apareceu.

Quem puder ajudar ficarei grato.
Att,

Comment: A `InnerException` pelo Visual Studio não dá mais detalhes?

Comment: Eu não consigo pegar a InnerException... Não importa aonde eu coloque try/catch ele nunca cai no bloco.

Comment: Você algum construtor estático no serviço?

Comment: Tenho o método Main, que é estático, mas o construtor da classe não é estático.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que o problema era uma variável estática. Havia uma definição que apontava para uma outra classe e ai ele estava dando uma NullPointerException.

Seguindo [este link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/67419/The-type-initializer-for-threw-an-exception) na solução de numero 5, o usuário disse para ir até o menu DEBUG->Exceptions e marcar todas as checkboxes para exibir todas as exceções possíveis, ao fazer isso o sistema me apontou exatamente o local aonde estava o erro na variável estática. Apenas removi a referencia a outra classe e tudo funcionou normalmente.